# Catalog New Product List Widget should have similar styles from category view

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, rwd-theme, category-products, widget

I'm using Catalog New Product List Widget to display all products on CMS page.

The output is messed up and they don't have filter, different pagination styles, no sorting options like with category view.

Is there any way I could use the same display like Category view.

I'm using RWD Package.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the above method, I try this which is much better.
I added this code to Layout Update XML.

```
<reference name="left">
   <block type="cms/block" name="Vaf Search">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>vaf_search</block_id></action>
   </block>
            <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
            </block>
   <block type="cms/block" name="New Products" >
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>new_products</block_id></action>
   </block>
        </reference>
<reference name="content">
 <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="product.wrapper" translate="label">
  <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
   <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager" />
   </block>
   <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
  </block>
 </block>
```

It allows to make the CMS to display all products.

I hope this help. If there is much convenient and much better just feel free to post.

Great thanks.